# proper use of viewcontrollers and MVC pattern in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I have often seen code examples being posted all over the internet wherein some view is added to the root view in ios within a view controller inside a lifecycle method in iOS.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 // Slider 1

 slider = [[[DCSlider alloc] initWithDelegate:self]];
 slider.tag = 0;
 slider.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,100);
 [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(controlBassValueDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 [self.sliderContainer addSubview: slider];

 // Slider 2 

 slider2 = [[[DCSlider alloc] initWithDelegate:self]];
 slider2.tag = 1;
 slider2.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,100); 
 [slider2 addTarget:self action:@selector(controlBeatValueDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 [self.sliderContainer2 addSubview: slider2]; 
}
```

But, doesn't it break the MVC pattern?

Because as per my understanding, ViewControllers are only supposed to be controllers and shouldn't directly partake in view modification related activities. Is there a way to structure the code in separate blocks of Views and Controllers?

Comment: Where else would you put code to setup a view controller's views?

Comment: And what do you think controllers control?

Comment: @rmaddy - Theoretically you could be doing this in a `UIView` subclass. But I don't think many would do that for something as simple as this example, but for really complicated views, I think the custom `UIView` subclass approach makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Funny, it was @Rob who answered my similar question months ago. Hope I am not wrong here. :P

Comment: In my opinion a lot of sample code, tutorials etc that you see on the web confuses people about what UIViewController does/is for and how it fits into MVC. It's UIViewController, not UIController.. I'll usually have a modelController object/graph as well because otherwise it is very easy for viewControllers to gradually become a 'God' class..  Good question btw

Comment: @codingVoldemort - I don't think you're wrong. My point is just that it's not a black-and-white issue. There are times where it makes perfect sense to move some purely view related stuff (i.e. code that has nothing to do with the integration with the model) into a `UIView` subclass. This just does not strike me as one of those situations (nor did your other question).

Comment: Makes sense! After the last paragraph, maybe I missed a "Alternatively, you can subclass..." paragraph. Hmm....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question.

And no, it doesn't break the MVC pattern.

Controllers "manage" the views ,which of course could be many; they may be manipulating the data to present it through the views; they may be manipulating the positioning of the views that are managed by it; or they could construct how those views themselves are presented -- which encompass what "managing" means. In this definition, I think it is safe to say that controllers SHOULD directly partake view modification without breaking the MVC pattern.

The `addSubview:` method within controller is OK! The controller is "managing" the view under it, by adding a subview which in turn is managed by the same controller.

Of course, if a view hierarchy is complicated and if a lot of views are doing a specific task independent of the controller, which you think could be modularised you can give them their own controller and add them as a child controller without breaking any pattern.